# creating javascript for table menu?

Tags: javascript, html

please take a look at the below:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEqvZg

im trying to work on the table.. sorry if the code is messy (still learning :))

so there are 2 things im trying to accomplish with the table:

1) Currently it's displaying the "Games" tab. I made a separate tab in html for 
"Collector's Edition", but that's hidden under .ces-display .

I want to toggle between the two.

2) In the "Games" tab, there is a menu of platform systems (XONE, PS4 etc). I'd like to be able to, click on the PS4 tab, and hide the current list of games, and show the PS4 list of games. the PS4 list is in html under .ps4-display

how can i accomplish this with javascript?

*EDIT: i also noticed that when the browser is resized, the columns in the table get messy. how do i fix this?

thanks so much everyone

HTML below, followed by CSS

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;'>
    <title >redwhiterocket</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/reset.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/main.css'>
</head>
<body class="debug">

<header class="menu">

    <a class="forum" href="#">forum</a>
    <div class="registration">
    <!-- login button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default #login" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
              sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover420753">log in</button>

    <!-- signup button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default #signup" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
              sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover420753">sign up</button>
    </div>

</header>

<!-- search bar -->

<div class="searchbar">
    <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
              </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">

        <div class="table">

                <div class="category">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                  <li role="presentation" class="type category-games"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation" class="type category-ce"><a href="#">Collector's Editions</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

    <!-- default display -->
                <div class="all-display">
                        <div class="platforms">
                            <span class="platforms-click">ALL</span>
                            <span class="platforms-click">XONE</span>
                            <span class="platforms-click">PS4</span>
                            <span class="platforms-click">3DS</span>
                            <span class="platforms-click">Wii U</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="topwrap">
                            <div class="toplist-wrapper">
                                <div class="top
                            ">
                                    <h3 class="toptitle">Buy</h3>
                                        <ol class="list">
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Deus Ex: Human Revolution</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Gravity Rush</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Destiny</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Silent Hill: PT</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Batman: Arkham Knight</a></li>
                                        </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="toplist-wrapper">
                                <div class="toprent">
                                    <h3 class="toptitle">Rentals</h3>
                                        <ol class="list">
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Bioshock: Infinite</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Tomb Raider</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Wolfenstein: The New Order</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Hotline Miami: Wrong Number</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Devil May Cry</a></li>
                                        </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="toplist-wrapper">
                                <div class="topfuture">
                                    <h3 class="toptitle">Upcoming</h3>
                                        <ol class="list">
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Mortal Kombat X</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Fallout 4</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Gravity Rush</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Battlefield 5</a></li>
                                        </ol>       
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

        <!-- PS4 display -->

        <div class="ps4-display hide">
                        <div class="platforms">
                            <span class="platforms-click all">ALL</span>
                            <span class="platforms-click">XONE</span>
                            <span class="platforms-click ps4">PS4</span>
                            <span class="platforms-click">3DS</span>
                            <span class="platforms-click">Wii U</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="topwrap">
                            <div class="toplist-wrapper">
                                <div class="topbuy">
                                    <h3 class="toptitle">Buy</h3>
                                        <ol class="list">
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Destiny</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Borderlands: Handsome Collection</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Gravity Rush</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Devil May Cry</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Fallout 4</a></li>
                                        </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="toplist-wrapper">
                                <div class="toprent">
                                    <h3 class="toptitle">Rentals</h3>
                                        <ol class="list">
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Thief</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Dragon Age: Inquisition</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">The Last of Us</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">FIFA 15</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Warframe</a></li>
                                        </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="toplist-wrapper">  
                                <div class="topfuture">
                                    <h3 class="toptitle">Upcoming</h3>
                                        <ol class="list">
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Batman: Arkham Knight</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Star Wars: Battlefront</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Mortal Kombat X</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">The Sims 5</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="list-links" href="#">The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask</a></li>
                                        </ol>       
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

        <!-- CEs display -->

        <div class="ces-display hide">
                        <!-- <div class="platforms">
                            <div class="ces-wrapper">
                                <div class="ces-click #ces">CEs</div>
                                <div class="ces-click #steelbooks">Steelbooks</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  -->

                        <div class="topwrap">
                            <div class="topces">
                                <h3 class="toptitle">Collector's Editions</h3>
                                    <ol class="list">
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">The Last of Us - Pandemic Edition</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Wolfenstein: The New Order - Panzerhund Edition</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Destiny - Ghost Edition</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Homeworld HD Remastered - Collector's Editon</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                            </div>


                            <div class="topces">
                                <h3 class="toptitle">Steelbooks</h3>
                                    <ol class="list">
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Deus Ex: Human Revolution</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Batman: Arkham City</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">The Last of Us</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Devil May Cry</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="list-links" href="#">Mass Effect</a></li>
                                    </ol>       
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </div>

<!-- image sizes 223 x 124 -->
        <div class="trending">
            <h3 class="trending-title">Trending</h3>
                <ol class="trending-list">
                    <div class="trending-list-wrapper">
                        <a class="trending-list-link" href="#">
                            <li>
                                <img src="http://www.gamesmediapro.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Deus-Ex-Human-Revolution-GamesMediaPro-image-22.jpg" class="news-pic">
                                    <div class="news-wrapper">

                                        <h3 class="news-title news-float">Deus Ex: Human Revolution Collector's Edition detailed</h3>
                                        <p class="news-paragraph news-float">For "select European countries," New Zealand and Australia! Nope, this edition of Deus Ex: Human Revolution is not coming to the U.S., Canada, or anywhere else.</p>

                                    </div>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="trending-list-wrapper">
                        <a class="trending-list-link" href="#">
                            <li>
                                <img src="http://www.gamesmediapro.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Deus-Ex-Human-Revolution-GamesMediaPro-image-22.jpg" class="news-pic">
                                    <div class="news-wrapper">
                                        <h3 class="news-title news-float">Deus Ex: Human Revolution Collector's Edition detailed</h3>
                                        <p class="news-paragraph news-float">For "select European countries," New Zealand and Australia! Nope, this edition of Deus Ex: Human Revolution is not coming to the U.S., Canada, or anywhere else.</p>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="trending-list-wrapper">
                        <a class="trending-list-link" href="#">
                            <li>
                                <img src="http://www.gamesmediapro.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Deus-Ex-Human-Revolution-GamesMediaPro-image-22.jpg" class="news-pic">
                                    <div class="news-wrapper">
                                        <h3 class="news-title news-float">Deus Ex: Human Revolution Collector's Edition detailed</h3>
                                        <p class="news-paragraph news-float">For "select European countries," New Zealand and Australia! Nope, this edition of Deus Ex: Human Revolution is not coming to the U.S., Canada, or anywhere else.</p>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <li><img  src="" class="news-pic"><p class="news-paragraph"></p></li>
                    <li><img  src="" class="news-pic"><p class="news-paragraph"></p></li> -->
                </ol>
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- SIDEBAR -->
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <h3 class="sidebar-title">giantQtips</h3>

    <!-- sidebar list -->
        <div class="sidebar-list-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-details-wrapper">
                <h4 class="sidebar-list-title">Out this week</h4>
                    <ol class="sidebar-list">
                        <li><a class="sidebar-links">Hotline Miami: Wrong Number</a></li>
                        <li><a class="sidebar-links">Borderlands: The Handsome Collection</a></li>
                        <li><a class="sidebar-links">Fallout: New Vegas</a></li>
                    </ol>
            </div>

            <div class="sidebar-updates-wrapper">
                <h4 class="sidebar-list-title">Updates this week</h4>
                    <ol class="sidebar-list">
                        <li>300 new users</li>
                        <li>Added 268 items to database</li>
                        <li>bi-weekly contests coming soon</li>
                    </ol>
            </div>

            </div>





        </div>




    </aside>

</div>

</div>


    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://bootswatch.com/assets/js/bootswatch.js"></script>
    <script src='javascript/main.js'></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* CURRENTLY IN: styles/main.css */

/* color ID #428bca for menu*/

/* RED 228,39,40 | YELLOW 239,145,53*/
/* table background 245,243,232*/
/* background-color: rgba(61,66,57,.1); */

body {
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: rgba(218,226,215,.7);
}

.debug .content-wrapper,
.content,
.category-games, 
.category-ce, 
.platforms,
.trending-list-wrapper,
.news-wrapper,
.all-display,
.ces-display,
.ps4-display,
.trending,
.toptitle,
.topbuy,
.toprent,
.topfuture,
.topces,
.sidebar-wrapper,
.sidebar-list,
.sidebar-list-wrapper,
.sidebar-list-title,
.sidebar-details-wrapper,
.sidebar-dates-wrapper,
.sidebar-updates-wrapper,
.sidebar-updates-title {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}


.menu {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 20px 17%;
    background-color: black;
}

.registration {
    float: right;
}

.login {
    margin: 0 20px;
}

/* search bar */

.searchbar {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 35%;
}

/* for content box */

.content-wrapper {
    margin: 20px 12%;
}

.content {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* for table menu */


.hide {
    display: none;
}
/*.ps4-display {
    display:  none;
}

.ces-display {
    display: none ;
}*/

.type {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.category-games {
    background-color: rgba(224,146,46,1);
}

.category-ce {
    background-color: rgba(55,136,78,1);
}



/* for platforms menu within table*/

.platforms {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0 3%;
}


/* platforms options within table*/ 
.platforms-click {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 8px;
}

.ces-wrapper {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 8px;
}

.ces-click {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border box;

    padding-right: 8%;
}

.list {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    padding-left: 8%;
}

.topwrap {
    padding: 0 0px;
}

.toplist-wrapper {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:;
}

.toptitle {
    font-size: 2em;
}

/*.topbuy,
.toprent,
.topfuture, {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
}*/

.topces {
    margin: 0 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}

.toptitle{
    text-align: center;
}

.list-links {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

/* News section */

.trending {
    margin: 50px 0;
}

.trending-list-wrapper {
    margin: 5% 0;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.trending-title {
    padding: 0 5%;
}

.news-pic {
    width: 25%;
}

.news-float {
    margin: 0 0;
    float: left;
}

.news-wrapper {
    float: right;
    width: 74%;
}

.news-title {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.news-paragraph {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}

/* sidebar */

.sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 27.5%;
    float: right;
}

.sidebar-list {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.sidebar-list-wrapper {
    padding: 0 3%;
}
.sidebar-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-list-title {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the input. was wondering what this string means? replace(/hide/gi, "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Javascript:

```
var gamesBtn = document.getElementById("games-btn");
var collectorsBtn = document.getElementById("collectors-btn");
var ps4Btn = document.getElementById("ps4-btn");

var gamesDiv = document.getElementById("games-display");
var collectorsDiv = document.getElementById("collectors-display");
var ps4Div = document.getElementById("ps4-display");

gamesBtn.onclick = function() {
    gamesDiv.className = gamesDiv.className.replace(/hide/gi, "").trim();
    collectorsDiv.className = collectorsDiv.className.trim() + " hide";
    ps4Div.className = ps4Div.className.trim() + " hide";
};

collectorsBtn.onclick = function() {
    collectorsDiv.className = collectorsDiv.className.replace(/hide/gi, "").trim();
    gamesDiv.className = gamesDiv.className.trim() + " hide";
    ps4Div.className = ps4Div.className.trim() + " hide";
};

ps4Btn.onclick = function() {
    ps4Div.className = ps4Div.className.replace(/hide/gi, "").trim();
    gamesDiv.className = gamesDiv.className.trim() + " hide";
    collectorsDiv.className = collectorsDiv.className.trim() + " hide";
};
```

As for the HTML, you need to add the IDs in the markup in the following way:

```
<li role="presentation" class="type category-games" id="games-btn"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="type category-ce" id="collectors-btn"><a href="#">Collector's Editions</a></li>

<span class="platforms-click" id="ps4-btn">PS4</span>

<div class="all-display" id="games-display">
<div class="ces-display hide" id="collectors-display">
<div class="ps4-display hide" id="ps4-display">
```

Full functional in this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emxaeo

Comment: thanks so much! i only asked for a few button because i wanted to study the javascript and do them on my own. so.. ill study your contribution and try to add more functionality myself. really appreciate the help! :) one question though (why cant i use line breaks here by pressing enter). what do you think of the overall HTML and css structure? you managed to pick up my codes quickly. is the structure easy to read?